# What is this shrub producing spherical fruits with maze-like skin?

Tags: identification, shrubs, fruits

The fruit is a bit greener than shown in the following picture and has a diameter of 8-10 cm (3-4 inches).

I was expecting to see them on a tree, but instead they were coming from tall branches of a shrub. Spotted on a trip to Silistra, Bulgaria in late September.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have closed it as a duplicate. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like Osage Orange (Maclura pomifera). Bulgaria fits, here is a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2JQoNQbT5M) which you can compare your tree with.

Comment: It's an Osage Orange, and I'd like to add that some have thorns as protection from large herbivores which aren't around anymore. It's also why the trees have very hard wood.

Comment: I love the idea that there are still remnants of mastodons today in the natural defenses of some trees and bushes.

Comment: Also called Horse Apples and Hedge Apples.